# Firebase store an user into database after signup with a custom document name (Firebase v9)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to store an user inside firebase database but with custom document name. What I am trying to achieve is that after the user signs up to the app, the app saves their details into a firebase database.

Here is my code:

```
function signUp(email, password) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(() => {
      addDoc(usersCollectionRef, auth.currentUser.uid,{
        email: email,
        password: password,
        id: auth.currentUser.uid,
        role: "user",
      });
    });
  }
```

As you can see I'm trying to save the document name like this: `auth.currentUser.uid`, which I put as the second parameter of `addDoc` function, but I get this error:

> Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Data must be an object, but it was: "B0P4tBzY2uOF2XG2o6cT..." (found in document users/Gmbv7Zd2JZF4PtTct4VF)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

addDoc will always generate a new random document ID.  If you want to specify your own document ID, don't use addDoc.  Instead, follow the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) and build a reference to the document to create, then create it with [setDoc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_lite.md#setdoc):

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 


setDoc(doc(usersCollectionRef, auth.currentUser.uid), {
    email: email,
    password: password,
    id: auth.currentUser.uid,
    role: "user",
});
```

Comment: I was actually looking at this solution, but I wasn't able to get it working, and now it works probably was missing something inside the function, thank you!